# My fetch requests are being canceled and i don't know why

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am creating a web app that consumes the https://restcountries.eu/ API.

When a user types a country, I'll make a request to the API using `fetch`. However, my requests always get canceled.

I tested the part which captures user input, but I think the problem is with my `fetch` code.

```js
var countryName; // This will receive the user input on a textbox in my HTML file.
var resultado;

function grabCountry(urlendpoint, countryName, endpointfields) {

  countryName = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;

  var urlendpoint = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/';    
  var endpointfields = '?fields=topLevelDomain;alpha3Code;callingCodes;altSpellings;subregion;population;latlng;languages;flag';

fetch(urlendpoint + countryName + endpointfields)
 .then(response => data)
 .then(data => {
   console.log(data())
})
}
```

[image: IMAGE: I always receive this error in the network]

[image: IMAGE: And this error in console]

Comment: Why do you redeclare variables that in theory comes as arguments when you invoke this function?

Comment: Actually i don't know, i am starting to learn JS now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've provided so far works just fine. You need to examine how you get your data. It should look like this for text or the `.json()` for parsing json.

```
fetch('/url')
     .then(response => response.text())
     .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var countryName; // This will receive the user input on a textbox in my HTML file.
var resultado;

function grabCountry() {

  countryName = 'Bulgaria';

  var urlendpoint = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/';    
  var endpointfields = '?fields=topLevelDomain;alpha3Code;callingCodes;altSpellings;subregion;population;latlng;languages;flag';

fetch(urlendpoint + countryName + endpointfields)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => console.log(data))
}

grabCountry();
```

Comment: Dude, you're a god!! But, you know what is strange? On my localhost the fetch request gets canceled, but when i make from a https host (https://nevesm.github.io/myfirstJS) it completes it!!! Thank you so much, i am finishing the app now, just need to treat the response and show friendly to the user xD

Answer (score 20):

One of the reasons for cancelled `fetch` calls can be that the HTML tag that triggers the event is a child (or grandchild) of an HTML Form tag. In that case the event might trigger the form which will start submitting the form data, thus it will naturally cancel your `fetch` call.

One of the solutions is to call `preventDefault` function on the event that triggers the `fetch` call. See example below:

```
function myFetchFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch("https://my-url-here");
}

<button onclick="myFetchFunction">Fetch</button>
```

Comment: In Chrome, it also doesn't like it when the event that triggered the fetch disappears from the DOM. So careful when hiding it in React before the call finishes! It took me too long to realize haha.

Answer (score 2):

Please do change the button type from `submit` to `button`. Your fetch will work like a charm!

<button ***type=button*** onClick="javascript:ticketCreation(document.getElementById('domain').value);">

Comment: that's the issue I had, thanks for the answer Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetch` code has a syntax error near the first `then` close.

```js
var countryName; // This will receive the user input on a textbox in my HTML file.
var resultado;

function grabCountry(urlendpoint, countryName, endpointfields) {

  countryName = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
  var urlendpoint = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/';    
  var endpointfields = '?fields=topLevelDomain;alpha3Code;callingCodes;altSpellings;subregion;population;latlng;languages;flag';


    fetch(urlendpoint + countryName + endpointfields).then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })


}

grabCountry('', '' , '')
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchInput" value="united" />
```